# At-sign before square brackets

Tags: javascript, e4x, demandware, isml

I'm currently maintainging some DS/JS code in Demandware and I just found that :

```
var XmlReponse : XML = new XML(result.object.text);
status = XmlReponse.@["STATUS"];
```

What does this unusual "@[...]" syntax do ?

It could have something to do with ECMA-357 specification (aka "E4X"), but I'm not sure : in the [DW docs](https://documentation.demandware.com/DOC1/topic/com.demandware.dochelp/ScriptProgramming/WorkingwithXMLData.html) (needs credentials), it is said :

*"You can read values from an XML object the same way you would from standard ECMAScript objects"*

```
var quantity = order.item(0).@quantity;
var singleItem = order.item.(@quantity == 1);
```

That seems to explain the `@` but let me skeptical about the following square brackets, maybe some kind of dynamic property ?

Thanks :)

Comment: Is that really plain JavaScript? What is the name of the file you found that in? More specifically what is its suffix/extension? Is it `.js`? I wonder because JavaScript doesn't have type-annotations either, which is in the line before the one you wonder about.

Comment: Not really pure JS, it is Demandware script, but it is meant to be ES5. I'll update.

Comment: @Benj it's not valid ES5 for sure.

Comment: And you're not using type-checkers like [Flow](https://flow.org/) (which can add additional syntax)?

Comment: In [the Demandware tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/demandware/info) it says that Demandware "... utilizes a JavaScript-***style*** scripting language..." (emphasis mine). Maybe it's not *real* JavaScript but its own dialect that adds additional syntax?

Comment: I don't know if we are using Flow or something else, with Demandware "the truth is out of there"

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Yes, it seems to be some custom stuff, but I can't help, to find it in their docs... Whatever, thanks for the advice, i now know that it is not JS and could be processed by some external tool/lib.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From reading the [ex4](/questions/tagged/ex4) [manual](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Archive/Web/E4X_tutorial/Accessing_XML_children#Element_attributes) it seems to read a property of an xml element. I don't see that reading the indexer would be any different

Your mentioned code would then read the attribute `STATUS` on the xmlresponse

The code on the linked ex4 manual status:

> E4X allows you to access the attributes of a particular element with the .@ operator. The most basic case would look something like.

```
var element = <foo bar="1"/>
element.@bar = 2;
```

Comment: And I suppose the `[...]` is for accessing only an attribute ? Would be `<item STATUS="..." ... />` ? Why these square brackets ?

Comment: @Benj I think it wouldn't really matter, the @ sign already points to an attribute, I guess you could just write `@status` as well, didn't find anything in the docs. Interestingly it is written with only uppercases, though xml spec normally says that all attributes should be lowercased

Comment: Yes, it is very strange. Thanks for your answer & Have a nice day :)